# KeyCloak is not able to communicate with DB all of sudden : throwing exception

Tags: database, jboss, keycloak

KeyCloak is not able to communicate with our DB and leaving below error message. However, we got rid of this by doing restart. But seems it is occurring often. Suggestions/Solutions would be better ...

Error Snippet:

> (Timer-2) SQL Error: 17008, SQLState: 08003 2019-11-25 23:35:21,389
>   ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (Timer-2)
>   Closed Connection 2019-11-25 23:35:21,389 ERROR
>   [org.keycloak.services] (Timer-2) KC-SERVICES0089: Failed to run
>   scheduled task ClearExpiredEvents:
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not prepare
>   statement
>           at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1692)
>           at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602)
>           at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:492)
>           at org.keycloak.models.jpa.JpaRealmProvider.getRealms(JpaRealmProvider.java:99)
>           at org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.RealmCacheSession.getRealms(RealmCacheSession.java:459)
>           at org.keycloak.services.scheduled.ClearExpiredEvents.run(ClearExpiredEvents.java:34)
>           at org.keycloak.services.scheduled.ClusterAwareScheduledTaskRunner$1.call(ClusterAwareScheduledTaskRunner.java:56)
>           at org.keycloak.services.scheduled.ClusterAwareScheduledTaskRunner$1.call(ClusterAwareScheduledTaskRunner.java:52)
>           at org.keycloak.cluster.infinispan.InfinispanClusterProvider.executeIfNotExecuted(InfinispanClusterProvider.java:78)
>           at org.keycloak.services.scheduled.ClusterAwareScheduledTaskRunner.runTask(ClusterAwareScheduledTaskRunner.java:52)
>           at org.keycloak.services.scheduled.ScheduledTaskRunner.run(ScheduledTaskRunner.java:45)
>           at org.keycloak.timer.basic.BasicTimerProvider$1.run(BasicTimerProvider.java:51)
>           at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
>           at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505) Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not prepare
>   statement

Comment: Any wrong in our data source config ?                                                           <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS" pool-name="KeycloakDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true"> 
                    <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@ourDB:port/ORCL</connection-url>
                        <driver>oracledb</driver> 
                        <security> 
                            <user-name>user</user-name> 
                            <password></password>
                        </security> 
                </datasource>

Comment: Please check how to ask any question in SO, In your question you didnt mentioned which database you are using ,Keyclok version ? Did you upgrade the keycloak? You have clearly mentioned your problem with proper details.

Comment: Could you edit your answer and cut-and-paste all of the stacktrace? The rest of the stacktrace indicates the root cause.

Comment: Thanks Everyone for spending time on this thread. However, this issue has been resolved .. Seems there was issue with keycloak and the latest patch update resolved it.

Comment: What version of keycloak was giving this error?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Everyone for spending time on this thread. However, this issue has been resolved .. Seems there was issue with keycloak and the latest patch update resolved it.

Comment: hi @Ravi Shank after updating to which version of keycloak the issue got resolved ?

Answer (score 0):

This connection pool change will work.

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS" pool-name="KeycloakDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
   <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://host.docker.internal:5432/postgres_db</connection-url>
   <driver>postgresql</driver>
   <pool>
       <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
   </pool>
   <security>
       <user-name>postgres_user</user-name>
       <password>postgres_password</password>
   </security>                 
   <validation>
        <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.postgres.PostgreSQLValidConnectionChecker"></valid-connection-checker>
        <background-validation>true</background-validation>
        <background-validation-millis>120000</background-validation-millis>
   </validation>                
</datasource>
```